# Message handler method in Delphi ignores that it is "private"

Tags: oop, delphi, windows-messages

There are two classes: `TBaseClass` and `TDerivedClass`, both in separate units.

**TBaseClass**

```
unit InhPriv.BaseClass;

interface

uses Vcl.Controls, Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, InhPriv.Messages;

type
  TBaseClass = class(TWinControl)
  strict private
    procedure TheMethod(var msg: TMessage); message WM_CUSTOM;
  end;

implementation

procedure TBaseClass.TheMethod(var msg: TMessage);
begin
  MessageBox(0, 'TBaseClass.TheMethod', 'IhheritedPrivateTest', 0);
end;

end.
```

**TDerivedClass**

```
unit InhPriv.DerivedClass;

interface

uses InhPriv.BaseClass, Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, InhPriv.Messages;

type
  TDerivedClass = class(TBaseClass)
  public
    procedure TheMethod(var msg: TMessage); message WM_CUSTOM;
  end;

implementation

procedure TDerivedClass.TheMethod(var msg: TMessage);
begin
  inherited; //TBaseClass.TheMethod gets called!!!
  MessageBox(0, 'TDerivedClass.TheMethod', 'IhheritedPrivateTest', 0);
end;

end.
```

**Host form**

```
TForm1 = class(TForm)
//.......
private
  c: TDerivedClass;
//.......
end;
```

`WM_CUSTOM` is defined as `WM_USER + 1`

**Calling the method**

*Variant 1: Sending a message:*

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SendMessage(c.Handle, WM_CUSTOM, 0, 0);
end;
```

Output:

> TBaseClass.TheMethod
> TDerivedClass.TheMethod

*Variant 2: Calling the method directly:*

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var m: TMessage;
begin
  c.TheMethod(m);
end;
```

Output:

> TBaseClass.TheMethod
> TDerivedClass.TheMethod

**CPU window**

It is a direct method call.

```
InhPriv.DerivedClass.pas.17: inherited; //TBaseClass.TheMethod gets called!!!
005B4880 8B55F8           mov edx,[ebp-$08]
005B4883 8B45FC           mov eax,[ebp-$04]
005B4886 E87DFDFFFF       call TBaseClass.TheMethod
```

**Delphi documentation says:**

*When **inherited** has no identifier after it, it refers to the inherited method with the same name as the enclosing method or, if the enclosing method is a message handler, to the inherited message handler for the same message.*

So, no explicit word says that converting a method to a message handler makes Delphi compiler violate OOP principles.

May I have missed some documentation?

Comment: Considering message handlers are meant to be "callable" even from a different process, I'm not sure what you expected there.

Comment: scoping the method private in the base class makes sure it cannot be seen in a descendant class (except when both are in the same unit). But in your descandant you have redefined the scope of `TheMethod` so you can call it anyway there. That is a little cheat I guess. The `private` scoping of `TheMethod` only meant to hide the method, not to make `inherited` not working.Correct me if I am wrong because this is just a guess to what causes this behaviour

Comment: Message dispatching doesn't care about method visibility. If `TDerivedClass.TheMethod()` tried to call `TBaseClass.TheMethod()` *explicitly*, that would not work due to visibility. But `inherited` doesn't care about that.

Comment: It seems, when I test this (in Delphi XE2), that having the message directive or not doesn't matter, but it's the fact of calling simply inherited without a method name that matters. That seems to bypass the strict private guard. Is this a feature or bug?